# Creating a folder and than writing many text files in it

Tags: matlab, text-files, printf

I want to create a folder called ‘all’ and after that I want to create and write many text files in ‘all’. The name of the text files being x1.txt, x2.txt, x3.txt & so on. Here is my approach but it fails somehow:

```
    folderName  = all;       
    mkdir(folderName);

    temp = ['x', num2str(k), '.txt'];
    fid2 = fopen('x.txt', 'w');
    fprintf(fid2, '%s\n', [folderName/temp '/' M{:}]); % M is a string, that I want to write in the text file
    fclose(fid2);
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using the correct symbol for the quote mark - you want `'` not `‘`

Comment: I just edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: What do you mean "it fails somehow"? How, exactly, does it fail? Are no files written? Is an error message generated? Also, you have not fixed the quote marks...

Comment: Is `folderName/temp` in `fprintf` a text that is to be appended to M and written to the text files or `temp` would be another folder inside `folderName`?

Comment: Also, at the start you have used `folderName` and then later on `foldername`. Are these supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
folderName = 'all';
mkdir(strcat(folderName,filesep,'temp'));

N = 10; %%// Number of files needed
for k = 1:N
    temp = ['x', num2str(k), '.txt'];
    pathname1 = strcat(pwd,filesep,folderName,filesep,'temp',filesep,temp);%%// creates the temp directory in the working directory.

    fid1 = fopen(pathname1, 'w');
    fprintf(fid1, '%s\n',M{:});
    fclose(fid1);

end
```

Thus, the files `x1.txt`, `x2.txt`, `x3.txt` and so on would  be created inside the directory `temp` that is inside a directory `all` and `all` is inside the working directory.

If you would like to create this directory `all` elsewhere, mention the full path for `folderName` at the start and edit the `pathname1` creation, like this -

```
pathname1 = strcat(folderName,filesep,'temp',filesep,temp);
```

Comment: I put everything you suggested below my M = B{1}(C) in my question and it works except that it try to create repeated folder 'all' from NN = 2 onward.

Comment: Get these before the loop starts - `folderName  = 'all';  mkdir(strcat(folderName,filesep,'temp'));`.